# Undefined constant in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am migrating an old code from 4.2 to 5.4. 
My index.php is triggering the error: undefined constant CURRENCY_BEFORE assumed 'CURRENCY_BEFORE

from this line:

```
<select name="curreny_position">
    <option value="BEFORE"
    <?php if ($curr_pos['value'] == CURRENCY_BEFORE) echo "selected"; ?>> 
     Before
    </option>
    <option value="AFTER" <?php if ($curr_pos['value'] == CURRENCY_AFTER) echo "selected"; ?>>After
    </option>
```

I am not sure if this would help, but this is the callout in my settings.php file:

```
{
    $currency_position = self::param('site', 'curr_position')['value'];
    $currency = self::param('site', 'currency')['value'];
    switch ($currency_position) {
        case CURRENCY_BEFORE:
            return implode(' ', [$currency, number_format($amount, 2)]);
            break;
        case CURRENCY_AFTER:
            return implode(' ', [number_format($amount, 2), $currency]);
            break;
 }
```

what would be the proper way to define CURRENCY_BEFORE above?

Comment: where did you define `CURRENCY_BEFORE`?

Comment: It is not called out here. I did not do the original code, but the other place it is defined is in a MedController.php; `define('CURRENCY_BEFORE', 'BEFORE');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest moving the definition of your constant to a config file

```
<?php
/**
 *  file: app/config/constants.php
 */

return [
    'CURRENCY_BEFORE' => 'BEFORE'
];
```

then you can call anywhere in the application by `Config::get('constants.CURRENCY_BEFORE')`